# how to loop over array in js after using array_unique in php

Tags: javascript, php

Came across this today :

```
$test = array('red', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'blue');
$test = array_unique($test);
```

Will return :

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [2] => green
    [5] => blue
)
```

This is passed to a js script through `$ajax_result['results'] = $test`.  Now how can I do a foreach loop in js since array_unique preserves the keys?

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++)
{
    //do something
}
```

They keys are no longer 0,1,2,3... *length, but 0,2,5 because they are preserved.

Comment: make it easy: just use `array_values()` in PHP on the resulting array to reset the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to support IE8 and you want those keys to be preserved:

```
var response = {results: {0: 'red', 2: 'green', 5: 'blue'}};
Object.keys(response.results).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key, response.results[key]);
});
```

Outputs:

```
0 red
2 green
5 blue
```

---

If you don't want the keys preserved:

```
$test = array('red', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'blue');
$test = array_values(array_unique($test));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
for (var i in response.results) {
    alert(response.results[i]);
}
```

Let's say you have an object:

```
var obj = { 0:"zero", 1:"one" };

for (var i in obj) {
    alert(obj[i]);
}
```